# Signout in gmail with asp.net website

Tags: asp.net

I am able to sign in in my web application through Gmail.
Now I am getting problem in sign out functionality.
My requirement is, when I signOut from My webapplication then it will do sign out from gmail also.
Currently I am able to sign out from My WebApplication But my Gmail Account is showing SignIn.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to try to achieve this functionality?  Is there a specific API call you're making to GMail?

Comment: "my Gmail Account is showing SignIn" how does that mean you have a problem?

Comment: Means I am logged out from my webapplication but gmail account is active n my requirement is whenever i logged out from my website my Gmail account should be automatically logged out.

Comment: Dear David I am using Google+ Api for log in in my website from Gmail found from https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/  By using these I am able to sign In but Not getting idea for sign out